# Lotus string matching Questionnaire system

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I have two string，must be split matching，and need 100%  the same count matches，how do this?
Thanks a lot for help

string A(Reply)

```
"01: 2"
"02: 2; 3"
"03: 3; 4"
"04: 3"
"05: 2; 4"
"06: 3"
"07: 2; 3"
"08: 2; 4"
```

string B(Answer)

```
"01: 2"
"02: 2"
"03: 3; 4"
"04: 3"
"05: 2; 4"
"06: 3"
"07: 2"
"08: 2; 4"
```

result

```
(Reply)"01: 2"    (Answer)"01: 2" =right
(Reply)"02: 2; 3" (Answer)"02: 2" =wrong
.
.
.
.
```

count matches=6

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SswO7.jpg

Comment: Sorry, your question is very hard to understand. Do you have Strings like `(Reply)"01: 2"(Answer)"01: 2"` that have to be split and matched or do you already have two different arrays where the single elements should be matched? Second question would be a very easy `For i = 1 to ubound(A)`- loop...

Comment: @Tode Thanks a lot for help, I renew my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still quite hard to understand.
This is what I understand:
You have a document with two multi value fields and want to compare these and count the "equal" values:

| Field A(reply) | Field B(answer) | Equal? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01: 2 | 01: 2 | equal |
| 02: 2; 3 | 02: 2 |  |
| 03: 3; 4 | 03: 3; 4 | equal |
| 04: 3 | 04: 3 | equal |
| 05: 2; 4 | 05: 2; 4 | equal |
| 06: 3 | 06: 3 | equal |
| 07: 2; 3 | 07: 2 |  |
| 08: 2; 4 | 08: 2; 4 | equal |
| -------------- | --------------- | ------ |
| Count |  | 6 |

In that case a simple For- loop can help:

```
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim fieldA as Variant
Dim fieldB as Variant
Dim i as Integer
Dim count as Integer

'- somehow get your doc
Set doc = ....

fieldA = doc.GetItemValue( "reply" )
fieldB = doc.GetItemValue( "answer" )

For i = 0 to ubound( fieldA )
    If ubound( fieldB ) >= i Then
       If fieldA(i) = fieldB(i) Then
            count = count + 1
       End If
    End If   
Next

Messagebox count & " equal lines found."
```

This whole thing seems to be to evaluate a test: In one field there are the correct answers and in the other the answers the person gave, and you want to know how many correct answers they gave...

Take care: If you save the correct answers directly in the document, then people can use Alt + Enter to look at the field properties and simply read out the correct answers from the fields and cheat like that.

If you are looking for a solution without writing LotusScript, you could add a computed field e.g. "CountRightAnswers" with the following formula:

```
_numReplies := @Elements( reply );
_wrongAnswers := @Trim( @Replace( reply; answer ; "" ) );
_numWrongAnswers := @Elements( _wrongAnswers );

_numReplies - _numWrongAnswers
```

What does this do:

- as a first step it counts the elements in field "reply" (=8)
- then it replaces all the entries in "answer" that exactly match the entries in "reply" with blank and trims the empty values. The result is: "02: 2; 3" : "07: 2;3"
- again: elements of these wrong answers (=2)
- Questions minus wrong answers equals correct answers

Comment: Since the question number appears in the entries in both fieldA and fieldB, this can probably be done without a loop in formula language, using @functions ReplaceSubstring, Trim, and Elements.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. But the question specifically had the tag "LotusScript", that is why I did not go down that route as well, but you are right: As it is only a few lines, I should add that solution

Comment: For your information: In this community you show your gratitude for helpful answers by accepting them (giving them the green checkmark).